# How is energy transferred to a resistor in an electric circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I'd really appreciate some help understanding this.

I've always thought that in a circuit, some source of potential (such as a battery) accelerates the electrons in the circuit, and that collisions between these flowing electrons and the atoms in a resistor are what transfer energy from the battery to the resistor. However, "Peter Upton's" answer in this [Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-electrical-energy-is-a-form-of-kinetic-energy) shows that kinetic energy is clearly not the vehicle for the transfer of energy from a battery to a resistor. (I know this is not the most reliable source, but given very low drift speeds and electron mass, the math does seem to work out.)

I have an alternative hypothesis: the moving electrons in a current are the source of an electric field, and it's this electric field that transfers energy to the more tightly-held electrons in a semi-conducting resistor. The electrons start to vibrate, and that's what makes the resistor feel hot.

Is this a valid explanation of how a circuit converts chemical energy from a battery to heat in a resistor?

Thanks!

Comment: Low average electron *velocity* does not mean the electrons have low average *speed*.

Comment: In Maxwell’s theory, energy is carried by an electromagnetic field. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector